# Final amount not changing after deleting the promocode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project where the user can choose the books and it will calculate the amount. Then it will ask for the support of books and then Promo code.

The above project is working but I am not sure my code is the best or not. or is there any best way to do?.

Let's talk about the issue.

I am getting the issue on promocode. What I am doing is, Once user enter the 5 character in the promocode than it will check the promocode is valid or not form the database. if valid then It will catch the total cost using                   `var finalAmt=$("#youPay").text();` and calculate the amount and display it. If no promo code then it will display the final cost.

I am getting the issue on `else` part. if user enter the first time correct promocode and it will calculate it but if second time user deleted the promocode then final amount should display but I not getting the final amount. I am getting the amount which user enter first time promocode.

Sample promocode is

```
BOOKS | 2%
```

Live example of the task

```
choose 3 books      3*5= 15
choose support Yes 15*2= 30
Enter promocode BOOKS 30 * (2/100)=0.6

Final amount 30- 0.6= 29.4

Pay amount is 29.4
```

if user deleted the promo code then my final amount is still showing 29.4. it should be 30.

There is some issue in promocode else condtion.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var discountAmt = [];
  discountAmt[0] = "0";
  discountAmt[1] = "5";
  discountAmt[2] = "10";
  discountAmt[3] = "15";
  var n = $(".checkBoxLabel:checked").length;
  var multiply = 5 * n;
  var totalAmount = $('#totalAmount').html("$" + multiply);
  var discountAmount = $('#discountAmount').html("$" + discountAmt[n]);
  var youPay = $('#youPay').html(discountAmt[n]);
  return [totalAmount, discountAmount, youPay];
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  var $checks = $('.checkBoxLabel:checkbox');
  $checks.click(function() {
    if ($checks.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
      $('.calculationStrip').hide();
    } else {
      $('.calculationStrip').show();
      var codes = myFunction();
      $('#youPay').html(codes[2].html());
    }
  });

  $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function() {
    $(".checkBoxLabel").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    var codes = myFunction();
    $('.calculationStrip').show();
    $('#youPay').html(codes[2].html());
  });

  $(".checkBoxLabel").change(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("#ckbCheckAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });

  /*Customization script here*/
  $('.support').on('click', function() {
    var codes = myFunction();
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
      var a = codes[2].html();
      var totCost = a * 2;
      $('#youPay').html(totCost);

    } else {
      $('#youPay').html(codes[2].html());
    }
  });

  $('#procode').keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length >= 5) {
      var checkPromocode = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/C_Registration/checkPromocode",
        data: {
          checkPromocode: checkPromocode
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(response);
          //alert(obj.message);
          var finalAmt = $("#youPay").text();

          var codes = myFunction();
          $('#promocodeMessage').html(obj.message);
          var sellingprice = finalAmt - (finalAmt * (obj.discount / 100));
          $('#youPay').html(sellingprice.toFixed(2));

        } //END success fn
      }); //END $.ajax
    } else {

      $("#youPay").text();
      $('#promocodeMessage').html("Please check your promo code");
    }


  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="bookList">
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_round show_on_click select_all" id="ckbCheckAll">Select All</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="book[]" value="1" class="all_checkbox checkBoxLabel ">Book One </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="book[]" value="2" class="all_checkbox checkBoxLabel "> Book Two</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="book[]" value="3" class="all_checkbox checkBoxLabel"> Book Three</li>
</ul>

<p>suport fields if user choose Yes then it will calculate the total cost mutiply by numbre of books. for example user chose two books then total cost is 10*2=20</p>
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="support" value="1" class="support">Yes</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="support" value="0" class="support">No</li>
</ul>

<!--amount display here-->
<p>Final Amount to pay:- $<span id="youPay"></span> </p>


<input type="text" name="promocode" placeholder="Code here" class="form-control promoField" id="procode" autocomplete="off">
<p class="pull-right"><span id="promocodeMessage"></span></p>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: what is  baseUrl? If not remove it.

Comment: @JasminMistry, baseUrl is my domain name...for example http://example.com.       I am using CodeIgniter but I haven't added the promo code fetch code that's the reason I haven't tagged CodeIgniter

Comment: `$("#youPay").text();` just gets the text of the element. You have to recalculate it just like you do in your `$('.support').on('click'` function.

Comment: @JayFridge, Yes,$("#youPay").text(); just gets the text of the element but how do I know that support button is selected or not in the else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$('.support:checked').val()` you can get the value of the currently selected radio button. I modified your code to utilize this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var discountAmt = [];
  discountAmt[0] = "0";
  discountAmt[1] = "5";
  discountAmt[2] = "10";
  discountAmt[3] = "15";
  var n = $(".checkBoxLabel:checked").length;
  var multiply = 5 * n;
  var totalAmount = $('#totalAmount').html("$" + multiply);
  var discountAmount = $('#discountAmount').html("$" + discountAmt[n]);
  var youPay = $('#youPay').html(discountAmt[n]);
  return [totalAmount, discountAmount, youPay];
}
var $totalCost = 0;
function checkPromocode() {
    if ($('#procode').val().length >= 5) {
      var checkPromocode = $('#procode').val();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/C_Registration/checkPromocode",
        data: {
          checkPromocode: checkPromocode
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(response);
          //alert(obj.message);
          var finalAmt = $totalCost;

          var codes = myFunction();
          $('#promocodeMessage').html(obj.message);
          var sellingprice = finalAmt - (finalAmt * (obj.discount / 100));
          $('#youPay').html(sellingprice.toFixed(2));

        } //END success fn
      }); //END $.ajax
    } else {
        var codes = myFunction();
        //recalculate the value depending on the currently selected radio button
        if ($('.support:checked').val() === '1') {
          var a = codes[2].html();
          var totCost = a * 2;
          $('#youPay').html(totCost);
        } else {
          $('#youPay').html(codes[2].html());
        }
      $('#promocodeMessage').html("Please check your promo code");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var $checks = $('.checkBoxLabel:checkbox');
  $checks.click(function() {
    if ($checks.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
      $('.calculationStrip').hide();
    } else {
      $('.calculationStrip').show();
      var codes = myFunction();
      $totalCost = codes[2].html();
      $('#youPay').html(codes[2].html());
    }
  });

  $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function() {
    $(".checkBoxLabel").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    var codes = myFunction();
    $('.calculationStrip').show();
    $totalCost = codes[2].html();
    $('#youPay').html(codes[2].html());
  });

  $(".checkBoxLabel").change(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("#ckbCheckAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });

  /*Customization script here*/
  $('.support').on('click', function() {
    var codes = myFunction();
    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
      var a = codes[2].html();
      var totCost = a * 2;
      $totalCost = totCost;
      $('#youPay').html(totCost);

    } else {
      $totalCost = codes[2].html();
      $('#youPay').html(codes[2].html());
    }
    checkPromocode();
  });

  $('#procode').keyup(function() {
    checkPromocode();
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="bookList">
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_round show_on_click select_all" id="ckbCheckAll">Select All</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="book[]" value="1" class="all_checkbox checkBoxLabel ">Book One </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="book[]" value="2" class="all_checkbox checkBoxLabel "> Book Two</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="book[]" value="3" class="all_checkbox checkBoxLabel"> Book Three</li>
</ul>

<p>suport fields if user choose Yes then it will calculate the total cost mutiply by numbre of books. for example user chose two books then total cost is 10*2=20</p>
<ul>
  <li><input type="radio" name="support" value="1" class="support">Yes</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="support" value="0" class="support">No</li>
</ul>

<!--amount display here-->
<p>Final Amount to pay:- $<span id="youPay"></span> </p>


<input type="text" name="promocode" placeholder="Code here" class="form-control promoField" id="procode" autocomplete="off">
<p class="pull-right"><span id="promocodeMessage"></span></p>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Let me check your answer, Give me some time

Comment: Yes, your code is working but I found one issue. I don't know It was before or not. What I did, I am on firefox browser, I selected the book, then support Yes then I entered the promo code till here no issue my cursor is still on the promo code field. then I pressed the alt + tab two times and it's changing the amount. that means promo code calling every time. I think I used keyup.

Comment: You could save your total cost in a variable and apply your discount on that instead of reading it from the youPay element.

Comment: Are you talking about in the script? should I store there?

Comment: I updated my answer and included a `totalCost` variable which I use in the ajax call to calculate the discounted price.

Comment: I tested everything from my side, Now I found another issue and that is, if I choose NO from the support radio then my promo code is not working. It's working only I choose Yes in support radio button.

Comment: I put the promocodecheck in a separate function so it can be called when the radio buttons change.

Comment: Let me check.give me some time to check

Comment: I am getting the error in console "i.nodeName is undefined"

Comment: I think there is a miss communication between us. What I am doing is, choose the book, choose support, and promo code if have. So I choose two books then I choose support NO or YES, I can add promo code If I have.

Comment: Where is `i.nodeName` coming from? The above code works exactly how you described. You can choose books, choose support and add a promo code. What of this isn't working?

Comment: Yes, This time it's working perfectly. I will accept this answer and upvote you after some time.... I just want to know that my code is the good code or should I use some more or advance code?